Just another basic puzzle
What's the word I'm looking for? Explain why.



The blank squares

 can be filled with TECHNOLOGY/ENGINEERING/MATHEMATICS (using the given set of letters). As the trunk of the tree, this loosely points at the STEM fields, and the highlighted letters anagram to the missing one: SCIENCE.

 I found this with a Nutrimatic query: 


Yup this is it!
